# White-wine vinegar mother & red-wine vinegar mother: what's the difference?

Tags: fermentation, vinegar, starter

Aside from the coloration (presumably from the wine medium), is there any difference between mothers for red or white vinegar?  That is, is it reasonable to use some mother from a red-wine vinegar to inoculate a white wine (or, for that matter, to create a "blush vinegar" by adding white wine to a red-wine vinegar batch)?

[This article](https://web.archive.org/web/20221225051005/https://www.epicurious.com/expert-advice/how-to-turn-wine-into-vinegar-article) says "keep reds and whites separate" but does not elaborate on why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There’s no difference, and there’s no reason to not make “blush” wine vinegar, other than that red and white wine vinegar can be combined to make blush vinegar, but blush vinegar can’t be separated into red and white.